# Selecting vector of variable A based on variable B

Tags: r, function, if-statement, for-loop, subset

How can I get a vector of elements from one variable based on conditions being satisfied in another vector? I am doing this so that I can graph segments of a population.

My attempt did not work, resulting in a NULL (empty) vector:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,3,3,3,4,1,3,2,3) # Conditional values
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) # Target values
df <- data.frame(a,b)

scissor <- function(x,n) {
  for (i in 1:12) {
    if (x[i,1] != n) {
      x[-i,] # Remove row that does not have value n
    }
  }
}

vector <- scissor(df,3)
```

Comment: Do you mean like `a[a==b]` or `b[b==a]` ? Please post the desired result

Comment: I want remove every value in b where (a != 3) so that vector ends up containing values (3,5,6,7,10,12) from b. I care less about removing vs adding to get the results, and I'm mainly interested in the best to extract specific values based on conditions in another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a double negation for what you're doing.

```
> b[!(a != 3)]
#[1]  3  5  6  7 10 12
```

But you can just do this for the same result

```
> b[a == 3]
#[1]  3  5  6  7 10 12
```

With a data frame, it would be

```
> df$b[df$a == 3]
#[1]  3  5  6  7 10 12
```

for just `b` values, and

```
> df[df$a == 3, ]
#   a  b
#3  3  3
#5  3  5
#6  3  6
#7  3  7
#10 3 10
#12 3 12
```

for the data frame.

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Actually this: df[df$b == 3, ]